request BETWEEN in fastapi orm
async def get_all(
            self,
            session: AsyncSession,
            order_field: str | None = 'created_at',
            is_desc: bool | None = False,
            **param
    ):

        if order_field is not None:
            if is_desc:
                k = desc(order_field)
            else:
                k = order_field
        else:
            k = 'created_at'
        objs = await session.scalars(select(self.__model).filter_by(**param).order_by(k))
        return objs.all()

I have legacy code that returns all objects from the database.
I need to change the code, or create a new method to return objects whose registration date is between two datetime dates.
At the moment, I'm just clinging to all the objects and cutting off unsuitable data in the code, but this option is clearly not optimal at all.

I am not really ffollowing: you don't even use the Django ORM at first sight?

From what I understand FastAPI doesn't have it's own ORM so it's not really clear which ORM you're using to me. Please [edit] your question and ask specifically about  the ORM you're using and add the relevant tags for it. Also the Django the isn't relevant for this question so I'm removing it (It might be similar for the FastAPI tag as well but I'll let the SMEs of that tag decide on that)

This question is similar to: SQLAlchemy: how to filter date field?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
